# Conditional 'Match to Any" Query - Possible?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, validation

Is it possible to to query a statement that equates to "IF ANY MATCH"?

Trying to accomplish:

```
if 
     @foo.bars.select(:bar_id) == current_user.bar.id 
     flash.now[:alert] = "Matches at least one record"
else
     redirect_to root_path
```

(need to run a query that checks if any of the :bar_ids gathered match that of the current_user.bar.id)

I hope that makes sense. Easy to write this out than to paste my whole complex application.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Active Record any?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-any-3F)

```
@foo.bars.where(:bar_id => current_user.bar.id).any?
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `Enumerable` (such as an array) you can use `.include?`. So you could do

```
@foo.bars.collect(&:id).include?(current_user.bar.id)
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was close!